# Why does taking logarithms on both sides of $0<r<s$ reverse the inequality for logarithms with base $a$, $0<a<1$?

Tags: inequality, logarithms, intuition

> Why does taking logarithms on both sides of $0<r<s$ reverse the inequality for logarithms with base $a$, $0<a<1$?

I would like some intuition on why this works. I tried graphing $\log_{0.5}(x)$ on Desmos, for example, and if the graph were true this would be evident from the graph, but the graph seems wrong because I don't get why as $x\to0^+$, $y\to \infty$ since $0.5^x$ should be $\le 0.5$ where $0<x<1$.

Comment: $\log_{0.5}(x) = \ln(x)/\ln(0.5)$ is decreasing because $\ln(0.5)$ is negative. And $0.5^x > 0.5$ for $0<x<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Because logs with bases less than $1$ are decreasing, not increasing functions.  As an example, we have $8 \lt 16$, but $\log_{0.5} 8=-3 \gt \log_{0.5}16=-4$.  It is like multiplying by a negative number, which is a decreasing function and reverses the inequality.

Comment: We might add that (or even begin with the thought that) exponentials of such an $a$ are decreasing functions, $0.5^2>0.5^3$ for example.

Answer (score 0):

Because
$\log_a(b)
=\dfrac{\log_c b}{\log_c a}
$
for any
$a, b, c > 0$.

The usual thing
is to choose
$c=e$ or $c=10$;
the key point is that
in both cases
$c > 1$.

Therefore,
if $b > 1$ and
$0 < a < 1$
then
$\log_c b > 0$
and
$\log_c a < 0$
so that
$\log_a b < 0$
and the usual inequalities
are reversed.